# How can I get my target string point/marker without moving the pointer?

Tags: string, mark, point

Lets say I have the following LaTeX code:

```
\ref{AAA}, \ref{BBB} ... \ref{BBB,CCC,DDD}

\begin{the bibliography}{99}

\bibitem{AAA}

\bibitem{BBB}
```

and I want to write a function that does:

```
(perform-replace "\\<AAA\\>" "\\<BBB\\>" t t nil 1 nil (point-min) BIB_BEG)
```

(asks if I want to change "AAA" --> "BBB" before BIB_BEG marker)

To get `BIB_BEG` I usually do (something like):

```
(let ((BIB_BEG make-marker))
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (search-forward "\\begin{thebibliography}" nil t)
  (set-marker BIB_BEG (match-beginning 0))
  ;; perform-replace stuff
  )
```

Now I was trying to do something like (I know it's wrong):

```
(let ((BIB_BEG make-marker))
  (string-match "\\begin{thebibliography}" (buffer-string))
  (set-marker BIB_BEG (match-beginning 0))
    ;; perform-replace stuff
  )
```

My question is, how can I get my target point/marker without moving the pointer? I already know I can use `(save-excusion)` to restore the initial position. In other words I was wondering if ther is a way to get the position I need with something like the `string-match` tecnique.

Comment: Could you provide some example before-after? M-x query-replace-regexp RET or M-x query-replace RET shall be options to use,

Comment: @AndreasRöhler Not in my case... I need to do it with a script.

Comment: Sounds like you're just looking for `save-excursion`. Wrap your point movement with that and when it's done point is restored where it was.